# Как сделать, чтобы автоматом включался режим показа скрытых файлов?

Tags: ubuntu

Убунту 10.04.

Для просмотра папок постоянно надо нажимать ctrl-H для того, чтобы появились в окне просмотра скрытые файлы. Доступа к ноуту нет ни у кого больше, только у меня!

Как сделать, чтобы автоматом включался режим показа скрытых файлов при открытии любой папки?

Answer (score 1):

Это делается в настройках проводника Ubuntu (nautilus).

1. Открыть проводник.
2. Зайти в меню Edit -> Preferences > View
3. Выбрать Show hidden & backup

Comment: Я это делаю каждый раз или ctrl-H. А как сделать, чтобы по умолчанию просмотр скрытых файлов был включен?

Comment: Эти настройки сохраняются после закрытия проводника и перезагрузки системы. Никаких дополнительных действий не требуется.

Comment: Почему-то не сохраняются!? После закрытия проводника и перезагрузки системы опять надо нажимать ctrl-H!Может поменять где-то в настройках?

Comment: Все, вопрос снят! Действительно все так как сказал альфа!Спасибо!